I want integration to turn $x^u$ into $\binom{m-u}{a-u}$
Like we have
$$
n! = \int_0^\infty e^{-t}t^n dt
$$
and
$$
\binom{n}{k}^{-1} = (n+1) \int_0^1 t^{n-k}(1-t)^k dt
$$
I would like to have a similar formula for the binomial coefficient $\binom{m-u}{a-u}$.
I know there's the complex formula
$$
\binom{n}{k} = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{|z|=\rho} (1+z)^{n} z^{-k-1}dz
$$
but that doesn't seem so nice.
Usecase would be that if we have a polynomial and we calculate a sum involving its coefficients, where the term $cx^u$ contributes the value $c \binom{m-u}{a-u}$, wouldn't it be nice to put that integration on top of the polynomial and let it make the result. Notationally nice, and also if we want to for example take a power of that polynomial and calculate the result, then also getting an approximation formula as the power becomes large.
Is there a name for this type of "generating function" where you get the term of the sequence by integrating?

I think that you should look for Sofo's theorems and possible extensions.
